# "List not found" error when deploying WSP to host-named site collection

Tags: solution-package, guid, host-named

We have prepared a SharePoint site collection with a site and a sub-site which we have saved as two WSP template files, including content.  These deploy fine to our Staging server when we put them into a path-based site collection.

However, our customer wants to use a host-named site collection instead.  When they deploy, they are getting a “list not found” error on the top site and a “Invalid Page Layout” error on the subsite.

Using ULS I can see that on the top site SharePoint is trying to access the Pages List using the GUID from our development server.  The GUID for the actual Pages Library is different on the Staging server, as the Pages Library was created when the Publishing Feature was activated.  I don’t see any easy way to update the baked-in list GUID which normally SharePoint would update as part of the deployment.  Especially as it is a system library.

I did find that this was a known issue up until the November 2014 CU, however, having upgraded the server to the December 2014 CU we still have the problem.

I have also noticed that for our Page Layouts on the subsite SharePoint has not updated the URLs (they still point at out Dev Server), resulting in "Invalid page Layout" errors.

Any suggestions for how to tell SharePoint the correct GUID to use for our Pages Library would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The only solution to this was to change the dev server to use Host Named Site Collections.  We exported the (path based) Site Collection and then reimported it using the Backup-SPSite/Restore-SPSite powershell from here:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc424952.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

We were then able to produce WSPs which the Staging server could understand - the lists updated correctly.